# hdfs.connect() vs HdfsClient in PyArrow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet, pyarrow

I apologize if this is a noob question, but I couldn't find any relevant reference -

what is the difference between these two?

If I'd like to read parquet files from hdfs using pyarrow, which one would I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `HdfsClient` API was deprecated, you want to use `pyarrow.hdfs.connect` now to connect: http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#hadoop-file-system-hdfs

Comment: pyarrow.hdfs.connect seems also like a messy solution [same issue as here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2113). Since you are everywhere on this subject, you look like the only one able to understand what's going on